# TOAD DB2 Like Operator

Tags: sql, db2, toad

I am trying to run a query in TOAD to hit DB2 source and help needed on correcting the syntax.

Trying to get values ending with LLC.

```
Select firstname, lastname
from Table a
where lastname like '%LLC'
```

It works if I use '%LLC%', but that would also give me additional results too.
I only need the ones ending with LLC

Comment: Your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be fine if lastname was a varchar.

Try

```
Select firstname, lastname
from Table a
where trim(trailing ' ' from lastname) like '%LLC'
```